# Why I hitting 350 table limitation in .edmx file in Entity Framwork

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, entity-framework, webforms

Why I can not add more than 350 table in the .edmx file while using Entity Framwork?
When I try to add more tables I see the following error

The incoming request has too many parameters, The server supports a maximum of 2100 parameters

Comment: You could try splitting your tables up into logical groups and have each group in their own edmx file.

Comment: Yes, I did that but with this way you miss more advantages if you put all them in one file.

Comment: You miss out on some performance but joins can still be done across ``DbSet``s.